# The parallel kth smallest algorithm with OpenMP selecting wrong number

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I am working on a parallelized algorithm finding the k-th smallest number in an array using OpenMP. Basically, I have a sequential algorithm that is based on quicksort and it works just fine.

```
//K'th smallest element in arr[l..r]
int kthSmallest(int arr[], int l, int r, int k)
{

    if (k > 0 && k <= r - l + 1) {
        int pos = partition(arr, l, r);

    if (pos - l == k - 1)
        return arr[pos];
    if (pos - l > k - 1) {
        return kthSmallest(arr, l, pos - 1, k);
        } else { 
                return kthSmallest(arr, pos + 1, r, k - pos + l - 1);
                }
    }
    return INT_MAX;
}

void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int partition(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    int x = arr[r], i = l;
    for (int j = l; j <= r - 1; j++) {
    if (arr[j] <= x) {
        swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
    i++;
    }
    }

    swap(&arr[i], &arr[r]);
    return i;
}
```

I am new to OpenMP. At first, I tried to parallelize the area of the function call itself in driver, unfortunately, it didn't work. The number drawn was correct, but it wasn't faster than sequential.

```
int main()
{   
    omp_set_num_threads(8);
    double start_time, run_time;
    int *data = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    clock_t start, end;
    
    printf("Creating the array.......\n");
    randomArray(data, N);
    printf("Created the array........\n");

    //start = clock();
    start_time = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {

        #pragma omp single nowait
        
        printf("\nKth [%d] value is %d\n", K,
            kthSmallest(data, 0, N - 1, K));
    }
    //end = clock();
    run_time = omp_get_wtime() - start_time;
```

When trying to parallelize the partition function itself, the timing improves, but the selected number is different each time.

```
int partition(int arr[], int l, int r)
{   
    int j;
    int x = arr[r], i = l;
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(arr, l, r) private(j) schedule(static)
    for ( j = l; j <= r - 1; j++) {
        if (arr[j] <= x) {
        swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        i++;
    }
    }

    swap(&arr[i], &arr[r]);
    return i;
}
```

What's wrong with my idea, how could I parallelize this algorithm correctly?

Comment: 1) What are `l` and `r` in the arguments of `kthSmallest()`? 2) In your first attempt only a single thread is executing the code, so you can't get any speed-up; 3) In your second attempt you have both dependencies between iterations and race conditions (different threads that try updating the same data at the same time), hence the unpredictable result.

Comment: @PierU sorry I forgot to mention it. The array is arr[l..r], so these are first and last element of the array. Which idea is better, or would you suggest a completely different approach? How could I modify the first approach so that the code is executing by all available threads? Or a second approach to distribute iterations among threads without mixing data?

Comment: Your algorithm is inherently sequential. OpenMP isn't magic, you will have to search for/develop a different algorithm that is parallelizable. I don't think that this is a good problem to start learning OpenMP.

Comment: This is basically a sort algorithm, and there exist know strategies to parallelize them. For instance, divide-and-conquer algorithms (as quicksort is one of them) [can be parallelized with OpenMP tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172126/openmp-recursively-subdividing-work-and-threads). However you are not using a full quicksort but a partial one (which is enough for what you want to do), and you can't take advantage of the tasks.

Comment: FYI: [Parallelizing std::nth_element and std::partition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18515772/10107454). Parallelizing just the partition using prefix sums might be instructive.

Comment: @PierU Is there any way to parallel what I have? Or it necessary to modify the current algorithm.

Comment: You algorithm is certainly QuickSelect. It is not easy to parallelize and known not to scale anyway. Prefix sums are not very efficient on most CPUs so I think it is a waste of time. Chunk based approach with atomic and prefix-sum are certainly one of the best way to parallelise it but this is far from being straightforward to do and the resulting performance is generally not very promising due to additional memory access (while QuickSelect can be memory bound on many platform or at least close to).

Comment: Note that QuickSelect is generally outperformed by the Floyd–Rivest algorithm. This last one also have a partitioning algorithm (recursively called). Parallelizing it is not simpler but it is at least faster in sequential. The use of AVX-512 changes things: the partitioning can be strongly optimized using instructions like compress. In the end, I expect the RAM throughput to be close to saturated with that on a desktop CPU. On a server one need to care about NUMA which make things really complex anyway. Note there are research paper on this topic: this is not as simple as it seems.

Comment: Oh and one last note: when the RAM is saturated, then using more core is useless since it does not make the RAM magically outperform its own limits. Thus, having a saturated RAM means that all algorithm will not scale better unless they succeed to reduce the amount of transferred data from/to RAM which is AFAIK not possible (data need to be at least read+written and compression would make that much slower).